# Using $translateProvider.useUrlLoader

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am using latest version of *angularjs* and *angular-translate*.

For some reason, I don't want to store my translations in static *.json* files (en_US.json or ru_RU.json)

Is there any API in *angular-translate* which calls a REST API which in turn returns *json* data for translation. REST API will pull the translations store in database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tale a look at:

http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translateUrlLoader

By default it will use the querystring param `?lang=` to pass in the desired language.

you would use it like:

```
$translateProvider.useUrlLoader("/path/to/my/endpoint");
$translationProvider.defaultLanguage("en");
```

Angular-translate will then make a call to `/path/to/my/endpoint?lang=en`

If you do not want a query string parameter, but would rather a path parameter, you can create your own loader based on $translateUrlLoader. Looking at the source, it looks very trivial:

https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/blob/master/src/service/loader-url.js

Comment: Is there any sample example of $translateUrlLoader ? Can i use $translateProvider.useUrlLoader instead ?

Comment: $translateUrlLoader is the factory that $tranlateProvider.useUrlLoader(...) uses. I have added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. What is the best practice when it comes to localization ? Shall i load the translations per page or load the translations for particular locale for entire website at once ?

Comment: @NoobDeveloper -- I would say start out simple, optimize it when if/when the language file gets too big. For now: load the application translation for the selected language/locale. If you later find your application is getting too big, and your language files are getting too big, you can break them into partials based on module -- and load the partial when specific modules are used. But for now -- keep it simple.

Comment: Can I user $translateProvider.useUrlLoader multiple times to set the Url because i have different Url for each language

Comment: @Vinod Louis, No. For that use the static loader. https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Asynchronous-loading

Comment: you mean individual static files json ?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you have different paths, use the static loader.

Comment: What if I need to load a new partial for the same language? I am not sure how that would work because lang parameter is not changing. Any idea?

Comment: You would use the translation partial loader in that scenario.